# Can't create object from custom class

Tags: java, class

I have a problem instantiating a class that's inside a custom jar file. The problem is that the project that contains this class, is being able to use the class, but once I build a jar out of the project, and try to use this jar in another project, I'm not being able to instantiate it.

for instance, this code:

`System.out.println("Reached here 1");
CustomClass customClass=new CustomClass();
System.out.println("Reached here 2");`

Wouldn't create the object, and wouldn't get print "Reached here 2". The other problem is that I'm not supposed to handle exceptions in this class just 'cause I'm not intending to change an earlier design.

Any suggestions?

Comment: More info is required. Is the jar that contains CustomClass in the classpath? Also are you getting errors/exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the .jar file itself. It was in the setup of my project. I should have included the .jar file in the ext folder inside the java directory which I didn't do. Thanks a lot for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to at least see what the exception exactly is without handling it:

```
try {
  System.out.println("Reached here 1");
  CustomClass customClass=new CustomClass();
  System.out.println("Reached here 2");
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw e;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but nothing is being printed!! Although I'm sure that an exception is happening..

Comment: It might be that stderr is lost: how about using e.printStackTrace(System.out) instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
   System.out.println("begin");
CustomClass customClass=new CustomClass();`
} finally {
   System.out.println("done");
}
```

If that doesn't print "done", your class is hanging during initialization. So give us more then. Like the class code :)

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you guys. The problem was that I had to include the new .JAR inside my JDK directory under the EXT folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get no error messages (and you dont do some `catch (Exception e) {}` in your code), as the "Reached here 2" is never printed, one thing I'd check would be whether the constructor of `CustomClass` simply `wait()`s for some notification and blocks the thread.

Try to spawn a different thread providing it with a `Thread.currentThread()` reference and then try to `interrupt()` the thread that's running the constructor after a timeout...